# Checked Photo of Input in Modal - Enable/Disable Button based on value of ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, angular-ngmodel

I have a modal that contains an input ID and checks if that specific input ID has already an existing photo on the database. If that input ID has a photo it will display it in the modal and make the button disabled and the user may input another ID to check. If the input ID has no existing photo, it will display a notification on the modal and the button will be enabled. I am using angularjs, html and javascript here.

My html modal looks like this.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="changeSCP" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Please Input SCP ID</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Current SCP ID:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="pull-right input-group inline form-control" value="" ng-model="scpIDView">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img ng-src='{{ oldphoto }}' height='250px' width='250px' class="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-6 control-label">New SCP ID:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="pull-right input-group inline form-control" placeholder="Digits Only" ng-model="newSCPID"></input>
                            <br>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="checkPhoto()" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="" contenteditable="false">Check Photo</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6" ng-show="checkedPhoto.length=='0'">
                            <h3 class="bg-warning" align="center" ng-show="loadingloader" src="img/loaders/4.gif" value=" No New Un-Arranged Product"></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" ng-show="checkedPhoto.length=='1'">
                            <img ng-src='{{checkedPhoto}}' height='250px' width='250px' class="" ng-show="loadingloader" src="img/loaders/4.gif">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" href="#" ng-click="savenewID(oldscpid)" disabled ng-enabled="checkedPhoto.length=='0'">Replace</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my controller, the checking of the photo looks like this

```
$scope.newSCPID="";
$scope.checkPhoto = function(newSCPID){
        console.log($scope.newSCPID);
                    $scope.loadingloader = true;
                    $('#loginloader').show();
                    unarrangedService.checkPhoto($scope.newSCPID)
                        .then(function(data){
                            $scope.checkedPhoto=data.data[0].photos;

                        }
                    );


                }
```

Comment: Do you get any error or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @KKK I didn't get any error, Its just that the photo isnt showing at all and the button is not disabled/enabled

Comment: Remove single quotes in the comparison since length is a number, not a string. ng-show="checkedPhoto.length=='1'" -> ng-show="checkedPhoto.length==1"  and see if it's working.

Comment: @KKK the photo still does not show either way

Comment: Remove href from ur button and there is no ng-enabled directive in angular and what does {{checkedPhoto}} print on your view?

Comment: @Vivz I removed hreh on my button. Still, the model {{checkedPhoto}} does not print any. But the API fetches the value in the background

Comment: What does {{checkedPhoto}} print on view? What data type is checkedPhoto?